# Latex list of symbols

Tags: symbols

I have seen that a number of packages exist that define symbols.

How can I find a list of just the core symbols provided by the Latex Team, but without the use of packages like `amssymb`, `MnSymbol` and so on.

Comment: Any decent introduction lists those. For example the "Not so short introduction" (`texdoc lshort`)  pp. 65--68.

Comment: Have you seen *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*? Yes, they list them all - Just ignore the irrelevant sections. https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: When you write "provided by the Latex Team", do you actually mean "provided by the LaTeX kernel"? (Hint: The "LaTeX team's" responsibilities go beyond maintaining the kernel.) Please advise.

Comment: as I have said in your earlier questions the latex team does not produce any fonts, so we don't produce any symbols. the computer modern and ams fonts are a required part of the latex distrubution so essentially your answer is amssymb.

Comment: Right.  I wanted to know about the ones required as minimum.  What happens when a user does not require `amsmath` ?  What happens then ?  Does not seem that `ams fonts` are the most basic symbols required.

Comment: you can look into the sources. The predefined math symbols are in fontmath.ltx.

Comment: Would you know the location of the file ?

Comment: @Mahavir `kpsewhich fontmath.ltx`

Comment: @Mahavir or typeset version `texdoc source2e` chapter B (page 598 and following pages)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX Team are not responsible for font production and the Computer Modern and AMS fonts are always available so the symbols provided by `amssymb` are always available in LaTeX, the package just gives them command names.

You can inspect the documented latex sources to see which command names are defined without any package by

`texdoc source2e` [or online](https://texdoc.org/serve/source2e/0)

in fontdef chapter B, pages following 598 which look like

...

[image]

...

Answer (score 6):

I would like to suggest that you go through the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) document *selectively*. The full 422-page document currently lists more than 18,000 symbols, grouped in 575 [!] tables.

- To accommodate your apparent aversion to using any symbols that are not directly provided by the LaTeX kernel, I suggest you check the document's table of contents (which itself is 12 pages long) and look only for tables whose captions do *not* contain disturbing words such as `AMS`, `pifont`, `tipa`, etc etc.
- Be careful: Some table captions may not contain a disturbing word, but a careful reading reveals that it's nevertheless necessary to load the `fontenc` package with options such as `T1`, `T4`, and `T5`. Since accessing these symbols requires loading at least one extra package, I will assume you want to exclude them from further consideration.

Applying these exclusion restrictions leaves just 24 tables. They are

- Table 1, LaTeX2e escapable "special" characters. E.g., `\$`, `\&`, `\%`.
- Table 2, Predefined LaTeX2e text-mode commands. E.g., `\textbullet`, `\textendash`.
- Table 3, LaTeX2e commands defined to work in both math and text mode. E.g., `\{`, `\}`, `\dag`, `\S`.
- Table 18, Text-mode accents. `\"{a}`, `\'{e}`, `\c{c}`, `\u{g}`.
- Table 48, Math-mode versions of text symbols. E.g., `\mathdollar`, `\mathsection`.
- Table 50, Binary operators. `\cap`, `\cup`, `\times`, `\div`.
- Table 72, Variable-sized math operators. `\bigcap`, `\bigcup`, `\sum`, `\int`.
- Table 89, Binary relations. `\sim`, `\approx`, `\equiv`, `\perp`.
- Table 113, Subset and superset relations. `\subset`, `\supset`.
- Table 123, Inequalities. `\geq`, `\leq`, `\neq`.
- Table 139, Arrows. `\leftarrow`, `\rightarrow`, `\uparrow`.
- Table 140, Harpoons. `\leftharpoondown`, `\rightleftharpoons`.
- Table 178, Extension characters. `\relbar`, `\Relbar`.
- Table 183, Log-like symbols. `\log`, `\cos`, `\arctan`.
- Table 188, Greek letters. `\alpha`, `\beta`, etc.
- Table 203, Letter-like symbols. `\in`, `\partial`, `\imath`.
- Table 222, Variable-sized delimiters. `\langle`, `\lfloor`, `rceil`.
- Table 223, Large variable-sized delimiters (must be used with `\left` and `\right`).
- Table 236, Math-mode accents. `\hat`, `\tilde`, `\bar`, `\dot`, `\ddot`.
- Table 246, Extensible accents. `\widehat`, `\widetilde`, `\overline`.
- Table 277, Dots. `\cdots`, `\ddots`, `\vdots`.
- Table 302, Miscellaneous LaTeX2e math symbols. `\aleph`, `\nabla`, `\infty`.
- Table 434, LaTeX2e musical symbols. `\flat`, `\natural`, `\sharp`.
- Table 473, LaTeX2e playing-card suits. `\clubsuit`, `\diamdondsuit`, `\heartsuit`, `\spadesuit`.

---

Just in case you're unsure about this: There is absolutely nothing virtuous, pure, or otherwise desirable about using only symbols that are listed in one of these 24 tables.